# Change Ribbon Button Enabled-Function

Tags: javascript, ribbon, custom-actions

I want to change the `EnabledScript` function of a existing Ribbon Button (Upload Document) but keep everything else, like the original CommandAction it executes on click. More specifically I would like to disable the Button in the Top-Level View, because there should only be folders. Inside a folder the Button should be enabled. (I have SP2013 if that matters).

I tried to change the button with a CustomAction but this only removed the whole button (see below). I also tried to modify the button with a Script that disables the button if needed but this did not work as exptected.

```
<CustomAction
  Id="AddDisable1"
  Location="CommandUI.Ribbon"
  RegistrationId="10002"
  RegistrationType="List"
  Sequence="999">
  <CommandUIExtension>
    <CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.New.AddDocument">
        <Button
          Id="Ribbon.Documents.New.AddDocument"
              Command="AddDisable1cmd"
          />
      </CommandUIDefinition>
    </CommandUIDefinitions>
    <CommandUIHandlers>
      <CommandUIHandler Command="AddDisable1cmd"
        CommandAction="javascript:return (true);"
        EnabledScript="javascript:uploaderEnabled();" />
    </CommandUIHandlers>
  </CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
```

I would prefer not to copy the button and only change the `EnabledScript` Section in the Command Handler. How can I change the Enabled function but keep the rest in its default state?

Update: Copying the Button as it is defined in the CMDUI.XML file and using `UploadDocument` as the command (default) and adding a Handler for UploadDocument did call the original functions and ignored my Actions.

As an alternative: If I cannot replace just the enabled-script, what JS does the original Upload Document Button call? This way I could at least create a new custom copy.